# CodeIgniter DataMapper Problem with Relationship

Tags: php, codeigniter, orm, codeigniter-datamapper

Hey i've got a pretty simple relationship in my Datamapper model..

in my model Ticket i hav:

```
var $has_one = array("user");
```

and when i try to

```
$ticket->user->get()->username;
```

it says:

> DataMapper Error: 'ticket' is not a
>   valid parent relationship for User.
>   Are your relationships configured
>   correctly?

i dont see the problem :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your user model look like? Does it map back to the Ticket as well?

```
var $has_many = array("ticket");
```

Comment: must i hav this back link or is it optionally?

Comment: You need to link back as such because otherwise the mapper has no way to tell how many tickets a user has. Say for example all users submitted only 1 ticket. If the system tried to guess, the whole thing would fall apart when a single user submits two tickets.